# How to keep DialogFragment visible after onClick on its adapter?

Tags: android

I have a `DialogFragment` with associated `SimpleAdapter` which listen for clicks. When I click on any item within a `ListView` the `DialogFragment` dismiss itself. How to keep it visible?

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.choose_file_for_import));
        mAdapter = new MAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.file_explorer_tv_filename, itemsList);

        builder.setAdapter(mAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int position) {
                File file = new File(pathList.get(position));

                        getDir(pathList.get(position));
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return builder.create();
    }
```

Comment: builder.setCancelable(false) ?

Comment: @blackbelt no, this doesn't work.

Comment: try `builder.create().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`

Comment: @mmohsinNaeem there is no such a method.

Comment: you try this? see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)

Comment: @mmohsinnaeem I'm using DialogFragment, not just Dialog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two choices:
Don't use AlertDialog.Builder or set `OnClickListener` after `builder.create()`.

### Setting listener after `builder.create()`

Set adapter with `OnClickListener` as a `null`

```
builder.setAdapter(mAdapter, null);
```

And after builder.create() assign `OnItemClickListener`.

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(...);
```

I must confess that I haven't tested it, I just looked in Android sources.

Comment: I'll try it, please also specify where you looked exactly.

Comment: Line: 921   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/AlertController.java

Comment: imho, I think my answer is better since it does not rely on undocumented behavior :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`setSingleChoiceItems()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setSingleChoiceItems%28android.widget.ListAdapter,%20int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) instead of `setAdapter()`. From the document:

> - `adapter`
>
>   The ListAdapter to supply the list of items
> - `checkedItem`
>
>   specifies which item is checked. If -1 no items are checked.
> - `listener`
>
>   notified when an item on the list is clicked. The    dialog will
>     not be dismissed when an item is clicked. It will only be    dismissed
>     if clicked on a button, if no buttons are supplied it's up    to the
>     user to dismiss the dialog.

So it should work the way you want, just use -1 as the `checkedItem` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the getView of the addapter and listen to the View onClick listener and inside this listener return false, this way it will tell the system that no one handle this touch event.

Check out this [sample](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).